# JBoss EAP 7 - Client JMS without standalone-full.xml?

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, activemq-artemis

I have two JBoss EAP platform: JBoss1 and JBoss2 (different boxes and obviously different standalone configurations). In the JBoss1 server I have JMS messaging (i.e. the `standalone-full.xml` configuration). In the JBoss2 client I have a `standalone.xml` configuration. When I try to connect this environment with JBoss1 I catch an error of misplaced or needed classes (i.e. ActiveMQ Artemis core classes). In the `module.xml` (the descriptor of my custom lib module) I put the correct dependencies, but the error is the same. The client in JBoss2 is a simple WAR with a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. In `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` I don't have the same dependencies in `module.xml`. Is this the problem? Or the configuration of JBoss2 client must be with a `standalone-full.xml`?

Comment: There's really not enough detail in your question to provide an answer. What exactly is the "error of misplaced or needed classes"? Do you have a stack-trace? How are you trying to connect the client on JBoss2 with the broker on JBoss1? Also, please share your `module.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Bertram, the problem is resolved: there are many *.jar concurrent in the lib custom directory module: ie, the artemis active mq jar and a old jms.jar with classes not compatible with active mq library. Thanks a lot....